# What would be a Pyspark equivalent of the SQL statement NOT IN

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**What would be the equivalent code in PySpark?**

If I have table A and Table B, and I want to select certain ID from Table A which is not in Table B, I can do the following SQL command:

Select ID 
from Table A
where ID not in (Select ID from Table B)

What would be the equivalent code in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a ["*left anti-join*"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html) with the option `"left_anti"`:

```
A_df.show()
# +-----+---+
# | type| id|
# +-----+---+
# |type1| 10|
# |type2| 20|
# +-----+---+


B_df.show()
# +---+-----+----+
# | id| name|type|
# +---+-----+----+
# |  1|name1|  10|
# |  2|name2|  30|
# |  3|name3|  20|
# +---+-----+----+


B_df.join(A_df, B_df.type == A_df.id, "anti").show()
# +---+-----+----+
# | id| name|type|
# +---+-----+----+
# |  2|name2|  30|
# +---+-----+----+
```

This would be equivalent to `select * from B_df where type not in (select id from A_df)`

In an SQL context (see [spark sql anti-join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join)):

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
# register dataframe as tables in the SQL context
sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable(A_df, "A_table")
sqlc.registerDataFrameAsTable(B_df, "B_table")

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM B_table LEFT ANTI JOIN A_table ON B_table.type == A_table.id").show()
# +---+-----+----+
# | id| name|type|
# +---+-----+----+
# |  2|name2|  30|
# +---+-----+----+
```

Here's how I created the dataframes:

```js
A = [("type1",10), \
    ("type2",20), \
  ]
AColumns = ["type","id"]
A_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=A, schema = AColumns)
A_df.printSchema()
A_df.show(truncate=False)

B = [(1,"name1",10), \
    (2,"name2",30), \
    (3,"name3",20) \
  ]
BColumns = ["id","name","type"]
B_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=B, schema = BColumns)
B_df.printSchema()
B_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Do you mean "left-anti"?  (Pyspark case) Cause this worked for me.
Thnx for the answer btw.

Comment: @AbhikHazra I believe they're the same but I will check

Comment: @user2314737- Okay, cool cool.
Maybe a version issue. For me, it said "anti" is not a proper method and listed out some others. And the below one worked for me:

B_df.join(A_df, B_df.type == A_df.id, "left_anti").show()

Comment: I assume since there's not a "right anti" that anti and "left anti" are equivalent (see also [Is there a right_anti when joining in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311964/is-there-a-right-anti-when-joining-in-pyspark). I'll edit the answer to avoid confusion. And yes, Spark changes a lot from version to version.