# pySpark check Dataframe contains in another Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Assume I have two Dataframes:

DF1: DATA1, DATA1, DATA2, DATA2

DF2: DATA2

I want to exclude all existence of data in DF2 while keeping duplicates in DF1, what should I do?

Expected result: DATA1, DATA1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left anti
When you join two DataFrame using Left Anti Join (leftanti), it returns only columns from the left DataFrame for non-matched records.

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1['id']==df2['id'], how='left_anti')
```

Comment: This is awesome, and what if I want to keep all data in DF1 that matches to DF2 which means expected result as DATA2, DATA2? I tried to switch the order but doesn't seem to work, it gives me empty result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311964/is-there-a-right-anti-when-joining-in-pyspark

Comment: if u want matching records do inner join

Answer (score 0):

`df1.except(df2)` will give you rows that present in df1 but not in df2

[image]

credits: https://sanori.github.io/2019/08/Compare-Two-Tables-in-SQL/